# XDomainRequest does not work in ie8 & ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I browsed many times and I tried many times, I am totally feel upset myself kindly please help me. I tried to send request with cross domain in ie8 , but it did not go to server side.

I search & reffered  and get many link, these are shows bellow

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/708881/Cross-domain-ajax-response-with-IE-and-IE
http://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

and manymore links

my code is show to below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>VAS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         (function(w) {
        var g = {};
        g.geoLocate = function(d, e) {

            if ('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) {

                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                console.log("started");
                xdr.open("GET", "https://someDomain/?k=sometoken");             
                xdr.onprogress = function(){
                console.log("ON progress");
                };
                xdr.onerror = function(){
                console.log("Error"); // i did not get here
                };
                xdr.onload = function(){
                console.log("onload function");// i did not get here
                };
                setTimeout(function(){
                xdr.send();
                },0);
            } 

            // IE7 and lower can't do cross domain
            else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1 &&
                    parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1], 10) < 8) {
            return "does not support";
            }    

            // Do normal jQuery AJAX for everything else          
            else {
            console.log("Else");
                $.ajax("https://someDomain/?k=sometoken", {
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset="UTF-8"',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: f,
                    error: function(a, b, c) {
                        console.log("Error"+a+b+c);
                    },
                    success: function(a, b, c)
                    {
                        console.log("Sucess"+a+b+c)
                    },
                    type: "GET",
                    timeout: 10000
                });
            }
        };
        w.idns = g
        })(window);
    });


    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="altContent">
        <h1>VAS</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

above shows ajax call or working fine with chrome and firefox browsers, but i need  to run ie8 and ie9 browser, kindly help me please. and i used jquery.1.12.1

Comment: `XDomainRequest()` is very outdated. Is there a reason you can't use a one of the stadard jQuery AJAX methods as you are later in your code?

Comment: But I think, we can't use AJAX in IE8 browsers. could you please share some solution for this.?. Thanks in Advance

Comment: i used this type of ajax , but it's not work for me https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Comment: What document mode is the page rendering in? (Use the Emulation tab of F12 tools to learn.) If the page is not rendering in the appropriate standards mode (which would be required for XDomainRequest), you'll want to change your [document type declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Depending on how you're deploying/testing the page, you may also need to add an `x-ua-compatible` header (use `IE="edge"`) and a [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) so the page opens in the Internet zone.